# How to get the returned value of rpc query in odoo12

Tags: javascript, return, odoo, rpc, odoo-12

Hi im having trouble in getting the returned value in the rpc query in the .then() function

here's my code

```
initialize_qr_code:function(){
            return rpc.query({
                    model: "pos.order",
                    method: "generated_qr_order",
                    args: ["Order 00001-023-0017"],
                }).then(function (qr_val) {
                    return qr_val;
                });
        },
```

I print the output of the initialize_qr_code() function like this `console.log(this.pos.get_order().initialize_qr_code())` in my console here's what i always get

`{state: ƒ, always: ƒ, then: ƒ, promise: ƒ, pipe: ƒ, …}`

but when i `console.log(qr_val)` in the .then() function i get the correct output

is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You get that log because you returned a resolved [promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

You can initialize `qr_val` in `PosModel` or use the code you wrote to call `generated_qr_order` function and use `qr_val` when it is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can store qr_val in you object variable, and then use it afterwards.

```
initialize_qr_code:function(){
            var self = this;
            return rpc.query({
                    model: "pos.order",
                    method: "generated_qr_order",
                    args: ["Order 00001-023-0017"],
                }).then(function (qr_val) {
                    self.qr_val = qr_val;
                });
        },
```